# primusrun/optirun slower than intel integrated

Tags: bumblebee

i just reinstalled debian 8, installed bumblebee on my laptop. I tried optirun glxgears, to check it worked, and all is fine.

for some reason, if i disable vsync, i get much higher results using the intel integrated graphics than using the nvidia one. 
intel:

```
rhiakath@aiur:~$ vblank_mode=0  glxgears -info | grep -v EXTENSIONS
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
GL_RENDERER   = Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
GL_VERSION    = 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
GL_VENDOR     = Intel Open Source Technology Center
VisualID 33, 0x21
32346 frames in 5.0 seconds = 6469.036 FPS
32110 frames in 5.0 seconds = 6421.822 FPS
```

and now for the nvidia part

```
rhiakath@aiur:~$ vblank_mode=0  optirun glxgears -info | grep -v EXTENSIONS
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
GL_RENDERER   = GeForce GT 630M/PCIe/SSE2
GL_VERSION    = 4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.65
GL_VENDOR     = NVIDIA Corporation
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
VisualID 33, 0x21
11828 frames in 5.0 seconds = 2365.596 FPS
12384 frames in 5.0 seconds = 2476.770 FPS
```

what's wrong here??? I remember using the nvidia gpu would be much faster! Did i forget something?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, check my fps [here](http://pastebin.com/ajbiL9Qn). this is on a thinkpad t450s on centos 7.1

Answer (score 1):

glxgear is not a good tool for benchmarking GPU. It contains hardly any work for the GPU, so most of what it is measuring is the CPU work and CPU<->GPU communication. And the latter will be better for Intel, as CPU and GPU are on the same chip.

Try some demanding game or a proper benchmark instead.

Comment: [Others suggested glxspheres.](https://askubuntu.com/a/658079/300811) I did. The overall frame rates are a lot lower but still my Intel integrated outperforms my NVidia GPU with 85fps and 69fps respectively. However, I am using the nouveau drivers.